# zsh: always buffer last command's output

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, linux-terminal

Is there any way of buffering or saving into a variable the output of the last command? e.g.:

```
% long_running_command
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>

% <oops! I realize I wanted to do a wc -l>
% long_running_command | wc -l
(wait a lot of time)
```

I'd like to have something akin to:

```
% long_running_command
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>
<long output>

% <oops! I realized I need the output, so I do the following>
% echo "$LASTOUTPUT" | wc -l
1586
```

Is there something like this?

Comment: This was recently discussed on the _zsh mailing list_, maybe you find some clues there: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00141.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you redirect the output of this long command to a file, and then use `wc -l`?

`long_running_command > output.txt`

`wc -l output.txt`

Or maybe store the output of this command to a variable and then `echo` it to `wc`.
`LASTOUTPUT="$(long_running_command)"`

`wc -l <<< $LASTOUTPUT`

Comment: The point of my question is that I forget to save the output somewhere (be it in a file, or variable), and I want to fix that after running the command.

Comment: There is no automatic way to save the stdout to somewhere... You need to say to your shell where and how do you wanna save it. Maybe in future this feature will be available...